# MIPS assembly, adding to jump

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, pcspim

I'm having trouble with my assembly code:

```
# Program testing 
        .text
        .globl  main

main:   ori $4,$0,1
        addiu $4,$4,2
        addiu $8,$10,4
        addiu $2,$1,1
        addiu $3,$1,1
        addiu $5,$1,1
        j main+8       #ERROR HERE
        sll $0,$0,0

# End of file
```

I want to add to my jump. My professor says this will work but I keep getting a parser error

My MIPS setting in PCSPIM are:
checked on bare machine, delayed branches, and delayed load.

Does anyone know what is wrong? Is there a word alignment issue?

Comment: Perhaps SPIM just doesn't support that. You could try `la $t0, main+8` / `jr $t0`, which SPIM seems to accept.

Answer (score 1):

There are no word alignment issues here.
Your problem is that the assembler you are using is not interpreting `label+displacement` as a target address.

As every instruction occupies 4 bytes, you are actually trying to jump two instructions ahead of the *main* label. Thus, just add a new label where you are really targeting the jump.

i.e.:

```
# Program testing 
        .text
        .globl  main

main:   ori $4,$0,1
        addiu $4,$4,2
jump_target:
        addiu $8,$10,4
        addiu $2,$1,1
        addiu $3,$1,1
        addiu $5,$1,1
        j jump_target       # main+8
        sll $0,$0,0

# End of file
```